# Case statement for different fields

Tags: sql-server

How could this be written?

I need to check a few fields for various conditions to determine whether to mark a record Y or N for keeping it. (I'm trying to exclude some records from a report where certain criteria are not met.)

I have tables aliased as ES, CQI, NA and CC in this example. So I need something like

```
CASE 
          WHEN SD.CType = N'ALT' AND ES.SERVICE = N'Alerts' THEN 'N'
          WHEN SD.CType = N'ALT' AND ES.SERVICE <> N'Alerts' THEN 'Y' 
          WHEN SD.CType <> N'ALT' AND ES.SERVICE <> N'Alerts' THEN 'Y' 
          WHEN SD.CType = 'BPY' AND CQI.PTYPE = 'BP' THEN 'Y'
          WHEN SD.CType <> 'BPY' AND CQI.PTYPE = 'BP' THEN 'N'
          WHEN SD.CType <> 'BPY' AND NA.BILL = 'Y' THEN 'Y' 
          WHEN SD.CType = 'BPY' AND NA.BILL = 'Y' THEN 'N'    
          WHEN SD.CType = 'LEN' AND CC.PTYPE <> 'CC' THEN 'Y'
          WHEN SD.CType = 'LEN' AND CC.PTYPE = 'CC' THEN 'N'
          ELSE 'Y'
       END    
          AS Keep
```

Basically these all include the SD.CType value, and then they get combined with values in 3 other fields. I could write a SELECT CASE statement in VB to do this, but I need this to run in SQL.

I appreciate any suggestions..thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with what you've got? You could nest your CASE statements, but this seems pretty straightforward as-is.

Comment: Thanks JNevil, it seems to work, but I was wondering if there's anything obviously inefficient about it, or if I should try some other syntax that's easier to read. I'm just not confident that all cases are accounted for in this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you getting an error while running this?  If yes, we need to see error and your query.  Also, since you've defined "Else 'Y' ", you do not need to add any logic in your case statement to identify 'Y'.

Example:

```
CASE 
      WHEN SD.CType = N'ALT' AND ES.SERVICE = N'Alerts' THEN 'N'
      WHEN SD.CType <> 'BPY' AND CQI.PTYPE = 'BP' THEN 'N'
      WHEN SD.CType = 'BPY' AND NA.BILL = 'Y' THEN 'N'    
      WHEN SD.CType = 'LEN' AND CC.PTYPE = 'CC' THEN 'N'
      ELSE 'Y'
   END    
      AS Keep
```

Comment: Thank you for that edit it makes much more sense now :P

Comment: My mouse is faster than my fingers :D